# How to pass data from casperJS to nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, v8, casperjs, qtwebkit

I built a scraper in casperJS that scrapes data from a Google+ page. It's working brilliantly.

Now I want to be able to add an API `GET` call in my nodeJS server that will grab that data and  return it in JSON.

I'm not finding any documentation or content on how to accomplish this besides in a testing scenario [here](https://github.com/n1k0/nodetunes/blob/master/Cakefile#L41). There is also [spookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS), but it hasn't been updated in 9 months and people are saying it is very broken.

Any guidance on making this possible would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use SpookyJS, the pretty much other option is to [spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) a new process from node.js.

Although, I don't think, it is a good idea to spawn a CasperJS instance with underlying PhantomJS for every API request. This will slow your API considerably. You probably want to cache the scraped data in a file or database and update it when it is necessary. The requests return immediately, but you may serve old data. This depends on your update interval.

I propose two alternative approaches:

1. Run the casper scraper repeatedly with [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) and collect the info. Select your update interval to your needs.
2. You receive a request and respond with cached/saved data. But you also can spawn the scraper with `setTimeout(runScraper, 0);` to break it out of the request processing. The request returns immediately and the scraper runs after the fact. It may update the data. If you receive too many request, you might want to run the scraper after a certain cooldown time again.

Comment: We're going to write the data to a mongoDB and then read it out from Node when we need the data. Since we're scraping reviews and they don't update that often (once a day), we can just run a cron job every day to crawl the pages. Does this sound like a good plan?

Comment: Sure, sounds good. I don't have any metrics, but my suspicion is that node may fail and so will node-cron fail. It may be better to run casper from the real cron. Otherwise, the usage of [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) is recommended.